# Parse string into bool, float, number, date or string

Tags: javascript

Assume that I have control of the inputs, I can create a functions that converts a string to correct type based on "best guesses".

```
'2017-12-24' -> string '2017-12-24' (implement with a simple regex)
'2017' -> number 2017 (implement with parseInt - ok to ignore any letters that follows)
'201.7' -> float 201.7 (implement with parseFloat - ok to ignore any letters that follows)
'True' -> bool true (implement with [].indexOf - TRUE, False, false, true also)
'foo' -> string 'foo' (implement withreqex - anything starting with a letter)
'' -> null
```

Are there any libs that already does this?

Comment: what is actually the question?

Comment: The question is "should I spend time writing this function that I assume someone else have already written? And if it exists - where is it?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [upcast](https://github.com/OmgImAlexis/upcast)

upcast is a JS type checking/casting library. Some examples:

```
upcast.type([]); // 'array'
upcast.is(123, 'string'); // false
upcast.to('foo', 'array'); // ['f', 'o', 'o']
```

This library may be unmaintained, but you'll get an idea to write your own.

Comment: Thanks, just the type of lib I was looking for. I'll keep it open maybe I'll get a few more suggestions